# DistanceMatrixService give status:ZERO_RESULT for some of the elements and some time run correctly

Tags: google-api

I am using getDistanceMatrix of google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(), but i am getting for some of the elements **status: "ZERO_RESULT"** while other element showing status OK, refer the screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/qu0s53
View question

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could not calculate directions from origin to destination that's why it return zero results in object

Comment: So would be there any kind of solution that Distance Matrix api always by force or any method will always able to calculate the directions?

Comment: Check that particular destination.When you get response form api you put condition , that only those destination fetch whose status is ok